# Where is the default launcher setting stored, and installing an apk directly into the file system

Tags: android, launcher

I have here a conference system that is based on Android. Since its functionality is very limited I want to try to modify the system. AFAIK there is no way to access the system configuration nor the file system through the UI of the conference system itself. And I haven't found a way to access the system using ADB yet, neither through USB nor Ethernet.

But: The whole file system is on an accessible SD-Card, so at the moment this is the only way to modify the system.

First thing I would like to do is to change the current launcher (which is mostly an interface for doing conference calls). I located the launcher in the app folder and found the entries in the packages list/xml-file in the systems folder.
My first question is: Where is the setting stored which apk is started as the launcher at the end of the boot process?

Second thing would be of course: Installing other apk. Is that possible, only through access of the file system?

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the setting stored which apk is started as the launcher at the end of the boot process?

Upon bootup, the system-server process launches the ApplicationManagerService, which sends an intent similar to any intent sent by any other application for launching another application in general. 
 Applications on the device which have the following snippet in their manifest are shown among other options which can handle the intent (including the default launcher) :

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

There can be a case where the os has set an application as a default launcher. There can be a couple of possible solutions for the case :

```
- Remove the application defaults by going to settings > launcher application
- Remove the default launchers programatically using adb (which isn't setup in this case physically , but can be done wirelessly)
- Override all default launchers in your application's .mk file using LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES
```

> Second thing would be of course: Installing other apk

You can try these methods for installing an application, if there's no direct way of installing one

```
- Use wireless adb using wifi/ bluetooth and install apk using adb shell pm install
- Pushing package to the filesystem and installing it by allowing external packages in settings
- Downloading the package from a webserver and allow the ApplicationManager to invoke the default PackageManager for the installation prompt
```